# Gmail SMTP Errors and False Positives: "The email account that you tried to reach does not exist"

Tags: email, gmail, smtp

Since earlier today, I've been receiving notification from Gmail SMTP alerting to "hard bounces", but the gmail addresses are valid and messages are NOT being delivered.

Here's an example of the alerts:

```
Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender

This is the mail system at host xxx.xxx.xx

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

The mail system <xxxxxx@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.140.27] said:
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please
try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser v17si54127wrn.60 - gsmtp (in
reply to RCPT TO command)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Should I report it to Google? If so, where should I go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There was a known issue with Gmail that Google has resolved.

#### This began on December 15, 2020 at around 4:29 PM EDT and ended at 6:51pm EDT. It only affected a certain subset of users.

9to5Google has [this info](https://9to5google.com/2020/12/15/gmail-address-not-found/):

> This afternoon, Gmail is seeing some widespread “Address not found” issues that prevent certain emails from being delivered.
>
> This issue primarily manifests as some messages not being delivered and users receiving an “Address not found” error shortly — around 30 seconds — after sending from Mail Delivery Subsystem mailer-daemon@googlemail.com.

And [the official Gmail status page at Google](https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=1&iid=a8b67908fadee664c68c240ff9f529ab) reads as follows; note that if anyone is still having issues they should check that link and perhaps the main “[Google Workspace Status Dashboard](https://www.google.com/appsstatus)” as well:

> **12/15/20, 6:51PM**:  The problem with Gmail has been resolved. We apologize for the inconvenience and thank you for your patience and continued support. Please rest assured that system reliability is a top priority at Google, and we are making continuous improvements to make our systems better. If you are still experiencing an issue, please contact us via the [Google Help Center](https://support.google.com/a/?hl=en#topic=4388346).
>
> **12/15/20, 6:09 PM**: We expect to resolve the problem affecting a significant subset of users of Gmail at 12/15/20, 7:00 PM. Please note that this time frame is an estimate and may change. The affected users are able to access Gmail, but are seeing error messages, high latency, and/or other unexpected behavior.
>
> **12/15/20, 5:44 PM**: Gmail service has already been restored for some users, and we expect a resolution for all users in the near future. Please note this time frame is an estimate and may change. The affected users are able to access Gmail, but are seeing error messages, high latency, and/or other unexpected behavior.
>
> **12/15/20, 5:18 PM**: Our team is continuing to investigate this issue. We will provide an update by 12/15/20, 6:00 PM with more information about this problem. Thank you for your patience. The affected users are able to access Gmail, but are seeing error messages, high latency, and/or other unexpected behavior.
>
> **12/15/20, 4:29 PM**: We're aware of a problem with Gmail affecting a significant subset of users. The affected users are able to access Gmail, but are seeing error messages, high latency, and/or other unexpected behavior. We will provide an update by 12/15/20, 5:30 PM detailing when we expect to resolve the problem. Please note that this resolution time is an estimate and may change.
> RSS Feed

And — for reference — there was a similar issue with Gmail that happened yesterday from around 7:20pm to 8:30pm EDT. More details on that incident [can be found here](https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=1&iid=109f5878e60fdfb3c0f64fc9b81752e1).

> “ Should I report it to Google? If so, where should I go?”

If you still have issues contact Google via the [Google Help Center](https://support.google.com/a/?hl=en#topic=4388346).